# Calculating limit of a simple sequence without guessing

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let's take the following sequence

$$ \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{2n^3 + \sqrt{n} +1 }{n^3} $$

I am having problems with solving these kinds of limits and understanding some of the strategies for solving limits in general.

I can't plug in $ \infty $ because it is not a number, right?

I know I can extract the $ n^3 $ to get an equivalent expression. But I am not really sure why I can/should do this here.

As far as I understand, rewriting a sequence as an equivalent sequence is done when the original sequence has an indeterminate form as its limit. So we instead calculate the limit of an equivalent (usually simpler) sequence whose limit is the same limit as the one of the original sequence.

If that' true and if I can't plugin in $ \infty $, how can I tell that this sequence's limit is an indeterminate form?

But even after simplifying and getting $ 2 + \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{n} +1 }{n^3} $

How do I proceed from here if I don't already know that something like $ \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n}{n^3} = 0$?

It seems to me that when solving limits, I just have to memorize some limits and recognize them or otherwise guess and use the $ \epsilon$-criterion.

Comment: Isn't it clear that $\frac {n}{n^3}=\frac 1{n^2}\to 0$?  Similarly, $\frac {\sqrt n}{n^3}=\frac 1{n^{5/2}}\to 0$.

Comment: Why do we extract $n^3$? Because it is the dominating term in the numerator and denominator. It is what "dictates" where this fraction actually goes. The remaining terms contribute nothing in comparison to the dominating term when $n$ is large. (You may say that $f$ dominates $g$ or $f>>>g$ when $\frac{g}{f} \to 0$.) And because $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n^3} = \frac{1}{n^2} \to 0$, because $n^2$ just grows when $n\to ∞$ but $1$ is just constant.

Comment: I really wonder when logically thinking people finally will stop speaking of "indeterminate forms", even though vast sections of their textbooks of calculus are exclusively devoted to *determining* their values. There are limits of sequences/functions, but (if they exist) they are *determinate*.

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{align}&\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{2n^3 + \sqrt{n} +1 }{n^3}\\&=2+\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{ \sqrt{n} }{n^3}+\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{ 1 }{n^3}\\&=2\end{align}$

Use :
$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{ 1 }{n^p}=0$ for $p>0$